# magento2 knockoutjs custom ship-to template binding

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, knockoutjs

There are some questions need your help.

Could you explain the following code? 
Can any one have idea how `address()` object works? 
At least Where can I find definition of `address()`?

```
<!-- ko if: (isVisible()) -->
<div class="shipping-information">
    <div class="ship-to">
        <div class="shipping-information-title">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Ship To:'"></span>
            <button class="action action-edit" data-bind="click: back">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'edit'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="shipping-information-content">
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('ship-to') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ship-via">
        <div class="shipping-information-title">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Method:'"></span>
            <button class="action action-edit" data-bind="click: backToShippingMethod">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'edit'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="shipping-information-content">
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getShippingMethodTitle()"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/ko-->


<!-- ko if: (visible()) -->
<!-- ko text: address().prefix --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().firstname --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko text: address().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().suffix --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: address().street --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: address().city --><!-- /ko -->, <!-- ko text: address().region --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().postcode --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: getCountryName(address().countryId) --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: address().telephone --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 2):

## How I usually debug UI Components

I couldn't find the exact code you need but here are some of my tips and findings, I'll use some related shipping address code as an example.

### Layout

The first step is to look at the XML to check the configuration, so open up `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` and look at lines 420.

```
<item name="shipping-information" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress</item>
    </item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shipping-information</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="ship-to" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/list</item>
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">ship-to</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Now this gives us some helpful information, mainly:

**Component** - This is the JS file which is a good place to look.

### The JS

Open up `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-information.js`.

Here you will find the logic responsible for rendering the shipping area, if you look on line 19 you'll also see the template used for rendering the information:

```
template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-information'
```

So let's have a look there.

### The template

Open up `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information.html` and here you will see many Knockout bindings such as `click: backToShippingMethod` on line 26. Now to debug that look in the JS file for `backToShippingMethod`. This returns the function:

```
backToShippingMethod: function() {
    sidebarModel.hide();
    stepNavigator.navigateTo('shipping', 'opc-shipping_method');
}
```

## Your example

I've used the above steps on your example and I've ended up in a maze of shipping and address JS. A few files look like they might be what you're after though:

- `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/new-customer-address.js` - I think this may be the one
- `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/quote.js`
- `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address.js`

I know this isn't an answer that solves your issue but I hope it helps, if I get more time I will revisit it.

Answer (score 1):

From what i known you can find the definition of address in:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-information/list.js

on line: 77